# Is the open square with a point removed still open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We define $$A=\{(x,y):|x|<1, |y| < 1, (x,y) ≠ (0,0) \} \subset \mathbb R^2.$$

So I drew the area that is defined by $A$ and concluded that $A$ is open. Also, the complement of A is closed because $\{(0,0)\}$ is closed per definition and $B=\{(x,y):|x| \geq 1, |y| \geq 1\}$ is closed as well because every limit point of $B$ belongs to $B$.

So now I need to prove this, but I don't know where to begin. Is there a way how I can show that every point $a \in A$ is an interior point? Or that every point $b \in B$ belongs in the closure of $B$?

And just in case, I know the  definitions of limit points and interior points.

Comment: You drew the area and concluded that it's open. And you know the definition of an interior point. Good. Now use the definition to prove your claim. (It might help to write out the definition clearly)

Comment: Well for interior points I need to show that there exists a R such that B(a,R) is a subset of A. But I don't know how to generalize this to all elements of A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $(a,b)\in A$ and let $r=\min\{\|(a,b)\|,|a-1|,|a+1|,|b-1|,|b+1|\}$. That is, $r$ is the smallest of these five numbers:

- distance from $(a,b)$ to $(0,0)$;
- distance from $(a,b)$ to the line $x=1$;
- distance from $(a,b)$ to the line $x=-1$;
- distance from $(a,b)$ to the line $y=1$;
- distance from $(a,b)$ to the line $y=-1$.

Then the open ball with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ is contained in $A$. Therefore, $A$ is an open set.

Comment: Okay this makes sense! "Then the open ball with center (a,b) and radius r is contained in A. Therefore, A is an open set." Does this need a further proof or can I just state this?

Comment: You might want to add that if $(x,y)$ belongs to that ball, then $(x,y)$ is closer to $(a,b)$ than $(0,0)$, and that therefore $(x,y)$ cannot be $(0,0)$. And that $(x,y)$ is closer to $(a,b)$ then the distance from $(a,b)$ to the line $x=1$ and that therefore $x<1$. And so on…